# getting heap space out of memory error- how is java heap memory used

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am reading a single XML file of size- 2.6GB-- the size of JVM is 6GB.

However I am still getting a Heap Space out of memory error?

What am I doing wrong here...

For reference, I output the max memory and free memory properties of the JVM--

The max memory was shown as approx 5.6GB, but free memory was shown as only 90MB... Why is only 90MB being shown as free, esp. when I have not even started any processing... I have just started the program?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Some have limits on how much memory one process can consume... i believe 32bit windows is max 2gb.

Comment: 2.6GB XML - OMG! Use a database!! Storing a XML File in memory will use much more space than the flat file on disk, because of all the node objects, child lists, attribute objects, etc.

Comment: @jlordo - reading an XML file with SAX or into a DOM can be a perfectly appropriate thing to do.  Depending on the requirements, a database could actually be the *worst* possible solution.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I agree, it **can be** perfectly appropriate. A 2.6GB XML is will never be suitable for DOM representation, and only good for SAX in a few cases. At this amount of data a database is a good choice because of memory consumption, query and manipulation opportunities and access speed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, when converting structured text to the corresponding data structures in Java you need a *lot* more space than the size of the input file. There is a lot of overhead associated with the various data structures that are used, apart from the space required for the strings.

For example, each `String` instance has an additional overhead of about 32-40 bytes - not to mention that each character is stored in *two* bytes, which effectively doubles the space requirements for ASCII-encoded XML.

Then you have additional overhead when storing the String in a structure. For example, in order to store a `String` instance in a `Map` you will need about 16-32 bytes of additional overhead, depending on the implementation and how you measure the usage.

It is quite possible that 6GB is just not enough to store a parsed 2.6GB XML file at once...

**Bottom line:**

If you are loading such a large XML file in memory (e.g. using a DOM parser) you are probably doing something wrong. A stream-based parser such as SAX should have far more modest requirements.

Alternatively consider transforming the XML file into a more usable file format, such as an embedded database - or even an actual server-based database. That would allow you to process far larger documents without issues.

Comment: +1 each byte turns into a 16-bit char at a minimum, each String which is every part of the file has about 32 byte of overhead.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/296735) where a 5MB XML File uses 60MB memory when read in java.

Comment: "It is quite possible that 6GB is just not enough to store a parsed 2.6GB XML file at once".  True. But the point is 1) Make *sure* you're running a 64-bit JVM (one that can use more than 2GB!), 2) use a tool like VisualVM (nee JConsole) to analyze exactly how much memory is being used, and where it's going.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4: Considering that typical DOM parsers require *four* times the size of the input XML file, the fact that if a 2.6GB file exists then a 4GB file is not unlikely and the typical memory available on most low-end and mid-grade servers I'd argue that this approach is broken by design and no amount of configuration, cajoling or prayer will save it.

Comment: Oh, and lets not forget that after you load the data in memory, you *still* need even *more* memory to get the actual work done...

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid loading the entire xml into memory at once and instead use a specialized class that can deal with large amounts of xml.

Comment: Absolutely.  Specifically, a *SAX* based class that reads just that portion of the XML that's of immediate interest.

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially several different issues here.

But for starters:

1) If you're on a 64-bit OS, make *sure* you're using a 64-bit JVM

2) Make sure your code closes all resources you open as promptly as possible.

3) Explicitly set references to large objects you're done with to "null".

... AND ...

4) Familiarize yourself with [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or [VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html):

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things7/
- http://visualvm.java.net/api-quickstart.html

Comment: Generally the JVM will refuse to start if too large a heap size is specified, e.g. if not enough physical memory is available or a 32-bit JVM is used and too much memory is requested. I assume that if the OP has managed to start a JVM with `-Xmx6144m`, then they are actually using a 64-bit OS and JVM...

Answer (score 1):

You can't load a 2.6 GB XML image as a document with just 6 GB.  As jhordo suggests, the ratio is more likely to be be 12 to 1. This is because every byte turns into a 16-bit character and every tag, attribute and value turns into a String with at least 32 bytes of overhead.

Instead what you should do is use a SAX or event based parser to process the file progressively. This way it will only keep as much data as you need to retain.  If you can process everything in one pass, you won't need to retain anything.